# Send email from magento2

Tags: php, email, magento2

I'm trying to send email from code in magento 2 like below:

```
$testo_email = '';
ini_set("sendmail_from", "noreply@test.com");
$from = "Sito Web www.test.com";

$oggetto = "Richiesta di contatto da sito";

$header = "From: indirizzo sito web <www.test.com>\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: Il nostro Php\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";

if(mail('mymail@gmail.com', $oggetto, $testo_email, $header)){
echo("Your message has been sent successfully");
} else {
print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

I am getting back the follow error:
Array ( [type] => 8 [message] => unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes [file] => /var/www/html/app/code/Magiccart/Alothemes/view/frontend/templates/themecfg.phtml [line] => 17 )

Can someone tell me what's I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Invalid serialization. Did you fill in a test string in the $testo_mail variable ?